# Pandas Dataframe every combination

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, merge, combinations

everyone!

I have a question, multi-dataframe merge, combination.

plz, check below csv.

I want every combination( user - content )

in other words, User have All contentInformation

plz, help me, thanks!

```
UserID Age
U-1    10 
U-2    20
U-3    30

ContentID ContentName Genre
C-1       T-1         Action
C-2       T-2         Game
C-3       T-3         SNS
C-4       T-4         Music
```

I want look below.

```
UserID ContentID Age ContentName Genre
U-1    C-1       10  T-1         Action
U-1    C-2       10  T-2         Game
U-1    C-3       10  T-3         SNS
U-1    C-4       10  T-4         Music
U-2    C-1       20  T-1         Action
U-2    C-2       20  T-2         Game
U-2    C-3       20  T-3         SNS
U-2    C-4       20  T-4         Music
U-3    C-1       30  T-1         Action
U-3    C-2       30  T-2         Game
U-3    C-3       30  T-3         SNS
U-3    C-4       30  T-4         Music
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer and let me know if it works for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A neat trick to do a cross join is to `merge` on a dummy column.

```
df1.assign(foo=1).merge(df2.assign(foo=1)).drop('foo', 1)

   UserID  Age ContentID ContentName   Genre
0     U-1   10       C-1         T-1  Action
1     U-1   10       C-2         T-2    Game
2     U-1   10       C-3         T-3     SNS
3     U-1   10       C-4         T-4   Music
4     U-2   20       C-1         T-1  Action
5     U-2   20       C-2         T-2    Game
6     U-2   20       C-3         T-3     SNS
7     U-2   20       C-4         T-4   Music
8     U-3   30       C-1         T-1  Action
9     U-3   30       C-2         T-2    Game
10    U-3   30       C-3         T-3     SNS
11    U-3   30       C-4         T-4   Music
```

---

If you want to set a `MultiIndex`, you'd do it by creating one with `MultIndex.from_product` and calling `set_index` on the result of the cross join:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df1.index, df2.index))
df = df1.assign(foo=1).merge(df2.assign(foo=1)).drop('foo', 1)

df.set_index(idx).rename_axis(['User', 'Game'], 0)

          UserID  Age ContentID ContentName   Genre
User Game                                          
0    0       U-1   10       C-1         T-1  Action
     1       U-1   10       C-2         T-2    Game
     2       U-1   10       C-3         T-3     SNS
     3       U-1   10       C-4         T-4   Music
1    0       U-2   20       C-1         T-1  Action
     1       U-2   20       C-2         T-2    Game
     2       U-2   20       C-3         T-3     SNS
     3       U-2   20       C-4         T-4   Music
2    0       U-3   30       C-1         T-1  Action
     1       U-3   30       C-2         T-2    Game
     2       U-3   30       C-3         T-3     SNS
     3       U-3   30       C-4         T-4   Music
```

Comment: first time see `MultiIndex` can solve problem rather than create the problem LOL

Comment: @Wen The MultiIndex is optional here, that's why :p

Comment: The MultiIndex way inspired me , Learn new thing ~ :-)

Comment: I get a MemoryError.
I use big data( User Data 220000, Content Data 6000)..

Comment: @Park.BJ Do you know what the size of `220000 * 6000` is? That's over _1.3BILLION_ rows. There's no way you can do a cartesian product on this data. Rethink your model.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit over think LOL.

```
df2['v']=[df1.values.tolist()]*len(df2)
df=df2.set_index(['ContentID','ContentName','Genre']).v.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index().drop('level_3',1)
df[df1.columns]=df[0].apply(pd.Series)
df.sort_values('UserID').drop(0,1)


Out[421]: 
   ContentID ContentName   Genre UserID  Age
0        C-1         T-1  Action    U-1   10
3        C-2         T-2    Game    U-1   10
6        C-3         T-3     SNS    U-1   10
9        C-4         T-4   Music    U-1   10
1        C-1         T-1  Action    U-2   20
4        C-2         T-2    Game    U-2   20
7        C-3         T-3     SNS    U-2   20
10       C-4         T-4   Music    U-2   20
2        C-1         T-1  Action    U-3   30
5        C-2         T-2    Game    U-3   30
8        C-3         T-3     SNS    U-3   30
11       C-4         T-4   Music    U-3   30
```

Comment: Definitely overthought :p